# Why can seasonality be characterised with a harmonic series $s_t = a_0 + \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \cos(\lambda_j t) + b_j\sin(\lambda_j t)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, time-series

Given that $s_t$ is a periodic function with period $d$, i.e. $s_{t-d} = s_t$, then time series seasonality can be characterised with harmonic sum:

$$ s_t = a_0 + \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \cos(\lambda_j t) + b_j\sin(\lambda_j t)$$

where $\lambda $ are fixed frequencies of the form $\frac{2\pi}{d}$ times some integer; $a_0, a_1, ..., a_k, b_1, ..., b_k$ are unknown parameters. Can someone explain why seasonality can be expressed as the afore-defined series?

Comment: Fourier expansion?

Comment: Any periodic function can be expressed this way.

Comment: To @YvesDaoust's point, technically any "nice enough" function on a finite interval can be expressed this way. Its Fourier transform would then be a periodic extension of the function beyond the original finite interval.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: $s_t$ is known to be periodic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed! It was just extra info for OP. I know I've seen a few textbooks that rely a bit too heavily on assuming periodicity when in practice one works with a function on a finite domain.